# Whenever I put value in rocksdb for the same key, the value get updated and count also gets increased

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

Whenever I put value in rocksdb for the same key. The value get updated. But the count by the following method db.getLongProperty(columnFamily, "rocksdb.estimate-num-keys") gets incremented.  Why am I getting this weird behavior?

Answer (score 3):

That is the expected behaviour in rocksdb. Note that the property is `estimate-num-keys`, meaning it will only give you an estimate( not exact ) of the number of keys present in the db. You might have to run a `full compaction` on the column family to get the accurate number of keys present.

Quoting from the WIKI,

> Q: Why GetIntProperty can only returns an estimated number of keys in
>   a RocksDB database?
>
> A: Obtaining an accurate number of keys in any LSM databases like
>   RocksDB is a challenging problem as they have duplicate keys and
>   deletion entries (i.e., tombstones) that will require a full
>   compaction in order to get an accurate number of keys. In addition, if
>   the RocksDB database contains merge operators, it will also make the
>   estimated number of keys less accurate.

You can also check the rocksdb option - `inplace_update_support` which will update the key if it exists in memtable itself instead of writing it again.